# Enabling ART on android

Tags: art

How much time it takes to enable android run time on Nexus 4.4.2 kitkat. 
I have near 90 apps installed.

I start it and screen comes that displays optimizing 1 of 90 apps.
After it got completed (all 90), screen with 4 colored circles revolving appears(i think that's the boot screen or something same when the phone is switched on), but keeps on for more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are in a bootloop.  If you've enabled android debugging, you can probably use [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Logcat) via `adb logcat` on your computer to read what's happening during the boot and figure out where/why it's crashing.  You'll usually see a crash message, and if you're in a boot loop, you'll frequently see a repeated cycle of text.

If googling samples of the log doesn't help come up with an explanation/solution, you might copy/paste that text, and (after verifying that it has no private information you don't want shared), paste it to a site such as pastebin.com or gist.github.com so that it can be easily shared.

Next, visit IRC (you can do this [from the web](https://webchat.freenode.net/) and try one of the android support channels such as #android to see if you can find someone to help "live".  You can show them the link to your bootloop log, and they will hopefully have a suggestion for you or redirect you to more information.

You can also update this question with a link to the logcat and maybe someone can help you as well.

As a last resort, you can always boot into recovery mode and do a factory wipe (or merely wipe the cache), which may help as well.